# where does stdio.o live in linux machine?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to manually do all the compilation steps of my program. In the last step where I use the linker command ld, I need to specify the object file for library(stdio as I have used printf in my code) then only I can make and .exe file. Where does this object file reside?

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest that you run `gcc -v your_file.c`.  That will let you see exactly what commands your linker is using.  You probably don't have an stdio.o file to link against.  Instead this is included in the C runtime library and the exact file will depend on your system configuration.

Answer (score 9):

stdio is part of the C standard library. The exact location of the standard library is system-specific, but it is often in a file called libc.a or libc.so.

In my machine this can be found in:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
```

You can ask `ld` for the search directory: `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR`.

libc.a is an [ar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29) ([man](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ar)) archive, and you can extract `stdio.o` from the `libc.a` archive using `ar` command:

```
$ # list archive member with `ar t`
$ ar t /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a | grep ^stdio
stdio.o
$ # extract stdio.o with `ar x`
$ ar x /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a stdio.o
```

Comment: yeah, there is no difference between stdio.h and stdio.o, both just have pragma settings saying that it is a gnu library . but the .h file has a few empty function declarations. i guess he is asking where the the files with the full function declarations.

Comment: @user135142 .h and .o aren't the same thing, there's a very big difference between the two. .h is a header file, it's used by the compiler during compiling stage; .o is an object file, it contains the compiled code of the library and is used by the linker during linking stage. Unless you explicitly download it separately, the full source code for the definition stdio is usually not installed in your machine. You'll have to fetch it from your distro's or GNU's source repository.

Comment: i heard that those .o files are static and are loaded at compile time. i think we need to view the source of gcc to view them.

Comment: Yes, compiled objects in .o files are linked statically by the linker, in other words, they're copied into the executable **after** compilation. Most C compilers would automatically call the linker after compilation, so many people don't need to be aware that compiling proper and linking are actually two separate stages during the compilation process. But yes, .o files don't contain the source code, they are after all, compiled.

Answer (score -3):

its probably under root

Somthing like `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib***`

Comment: i am not sure of that  .. but definately in `/usr`

Comment: Not necessarily true - just because the question suggests that the OP might not have compiled his own stdio, doesn't mean that the system admin didn't place it somewhere else. Placement in /lib{,32,64} wouldn't be too disruptive for a normal ld-config setup, and with tweaked paths it could easily be anywhere the sysadmin wanted (although looking somewhere like /temp would be a good way to waste your time! :) )

Comment: @chrisb2244 it's also not clear (to me) that the OP actually has compiled stdio.