# C header and source file confusion

Tags: c, gcc, reference, header, include

I wrote myself a littly module I want to reuse. I got my header file `bitstream.h` with a struct and function declarations and `bitstream.c` with the implementations. Now I'd like to use this in my other programs, but without manually compiling `bitstream.c` every time, like you don't have to compile `stdio.h` every time you use it, but I don't get it to work. My files look like this:

#### bitstream.c

```
#include "bitstream.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bit_stream_t *fbit_stream(const char *path) {
    FILE *f;

    /* open file for reading */
    f = fopen(path, "rb");

    ...
```

#### bitstream.h

```
#ifndef BITSTREAM_H
#define BITSTREAM_H

#define EOS 0x0a

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int i_byte;
    unsigned char i_bit;
    unsigned char current_bit;
    unsigned char *bytes;
} bit_stream_t;

extern bit_stream_t *fbit_stream(const char *path);
extern unsigned char bit_stream_next(bit_stream_t *bs);
extern void bit_stream_close(bit_stream_t *bs);
extern void print_bit_stream(bit_stream_t *bs);

#endif
```

I put these two files into `/usr/local/include` (I'm on a Linux machine) and now I'd like to use this in `main.c` (somewhere else, e.g. `/home/foo/main.c`):

#### main.c

```
#include <bitstream.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Need 1 argument!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    bit_stream_t *my_bs;
    my_bs = fbit_stream(argv[1]);

    while (my_bs -> current_bit != EOS) {
        printf("%d", my_bs -> current_bit);
        bit_stream_next(my_bs);
    }

    bit_stream_close(my_bs);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I try `gcc -Wall -o main.o main.c` I get

```
/tmp/ccgdq66W.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x35): Undefined reference to `fbit_stream'
main.c:(.text+0x63): Undefined reference to `bit_stream_next'
main.c:(.text+0x7b): Undefined reference to `bit_stream_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**What am I doing wrong?** Thanks in advance for any help!

smuecke

Comment: The errors are from your linker, not the compiler. It's because you're not compiling bitstream.c and so the linker cannot find the definitions.

Comment: `stdio`isn't just a header. Take a look on [Lie Ryan answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27352493/5118690). I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you don't need to "compile" `stdio.h` every time is that it's implementations (and a lot more) are already compiled and live at [GLibC](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). That is, `glibc` is a library (a dynamic one) and GCC links your programs to it everytime you compile them. You can check that by running:

```
ldd hello
```

assuming `hello` is a simple **Hello World!** program that uses `printf`, for instance. And you'd get something like:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5f98d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7e985b2000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7e98977000)
```

See the line 2: `libc.so.6`, that's your GNU C Library, and that's the reason you don't "compile" `stdio.h` every time you use it.

---

### General Case

What you want to do is implement your own library. So, in order to do that, you can do several things.

1. You create a directory under `/usr/include` called `MyLib` and put all your headers there. This way you can include your files using `#include <MyLib/myHeader.h>`.
2. **Method 1:** You compile your implementation `myImp.c` into an object file and put that object in a folder, `/my/libs/path/myImp.o` and every time you want to use, you compile with:

   `gcc -o prog prog.c /my/libs/path/myImp.o`

   *Note: prog.c must `#include <MyLibs/myHeader.h>`.*
3. **Method 2:** You can make an archive with the utility `ar` and have all your libraries in it. Check it's [manual here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar). Every time you want to use something from your library, you link it with the `.a` library.
4. **Method 3:** You can make a dynamic library, which will decrease the size of your binaries (linking .o and `ar` libraries is static linking, which means larger binary sizes). You can do that using the `-fPIC` (Position Independent Code) `gcc` flag and some other small things. I'll link some resources .

---

### Your specific case

1. Compile `bitstream.c` with `gcc -c bitstream.c`.
2. Put that file in `/home/you/myLibs/bitstream.o`.
3. Copy the `bitstream.h` to `/usr/include/MyLib/bitstream.h` (you'll need **root**)
4. Include that with `#include <MyLib/bitstream.h>`
5. Compile your program with: `gcc -o main main.c ~/myLibs/bitstream.o`.

Although this is far from good, this will do what you want. I suggest you read up on how to organize your own libraries and more, check out [Rusty Russel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusty_Russell)'s [CCAN Library](https://github.com/rustyrussell/ccan/), pretty good starting point on how to build C libraries.

I **really** recommend checking out CCAN!

---

### Resources

- [Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)
- [Shared libraries with GCC on Linux](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html)
- [GNU C Library Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/)
- [How to Build Your Own C Library](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Ecampbell/cs50/buildlib.html)

Comment: OK, so as I understand it, there is no way around adding `/foo/bitstream.o` when using my own libraries, because stuff like `stdio` and `math` is always "alive" in gcc?

Comment: @smuecke No, they're not "alive" **in gcc**. GCC is a compiler suite. Stuff like `stdio.h` are headers which define prototypes of functions in libraries. These libraries are compiled **using GCC** and live at files in your system. `stdio.h` for example, is in `glibc`.

Comment: @smuecke And no, there's no way around having a compiled object file `/foo/bitstream.o` or `/foo/bitstream.a` (archive) or `/lib/bitsream.so` (shared). You need those in order to tell GCC to link them with your program.

Answer (score 3):

compile bitstream.c to create bitstream.o

```
gcc -Wall -c bitstream.c
```

compile main.c and bitstream.o to create main (or main.exe if on winX)

```
gcc -Wall -o main main.c bitstream.o
```